# Какая разница между определениями класса в Js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, столкнулся на проекте с двумя разными объявлениями классов в Js

Первый вариант:

```
let ClassName = class {...}
```

Второй вариант:

```
class ClassName {...}
```

Какая разница между этими определениями?

Comment: особой разницы нет. и в документации всё написано https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Первый вариант ещё требует точки с запятой (если, конечно, их в коде принято ставить после всех инструкций), второй — нет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Через let объявляется переменная, которой можно потом присвоить другое значение.
2. В class expression можно задать классу другое имя, которое будет видимо только внутри него.
3. С class decloaration можно нормально использовать export.

Больше разницы пока не вижу, даже имя класса по умолчанию возьмётся из переменной.